# Questions about orders table for mulltiple items with multiple options

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am making a new database for an online store and Am trying to figure out how to do the orders table. There are multiple products and each product has many options. I am just wondering the best way to keep track of all this. I keep coming back to a table with all the options for all the items. This seems like a bad thing though. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: To few details. A structure (even partial) of relevant tables would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

- Every product is stored in a row of table **product**
- Every product has zero or N **options** ( 0 N )
- Every **order** contain one or N products ( 0 N )

You need 4 tables to keep track for all this : options, products ,  products_orders , orders

Comment: Seems like a product_options table would be good too, what do you think?

Comment: Sure, like for products_orders, he'll need that table for options.. i missed that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with the table structure below as a base.  You will almost definately need more columns than the ones i have included but it seems to me that you need what is below at a minimum.

```
Order
-----
   orderId
   someOtherColumn

OrderProducts
-------------
   orderId
   ProductId

product
--------
   productId
   productName


productOption
-------------
   productId
   OptionId

Option
--------
   OptionId
   OptionName
```